# Dose anyone know Help Authoring Tools for User Guide and Source document?

Tags: java, help-authoring

I have a larg scale program and I have to create a perfect User Guide and a Source document for it.

I have used 2 difrent tools for user guide and source document in Java.
Now I need some tools that have these tow option in one(**Source Document Generator** and **User Guide Generator**) .
please help me out with this

Comment: Is your program is an API? What do you need to document?

Answer (score 2):

If your program is an API, I would suggest [swagger.io](https://swagger.io) .

If you want more generic technical documentation tools you can look at the following softwares:

1. [HelpNdoc](https://www.helpndoc.com/)
2. [ClickHelp](https://clickhelp.com/)
3. [Whatfix](https://whatfix.com/)
4. [ProcessStreet](https://www.process.st/)